# Is it possible to know if I was BCC'd directly or as part of a mail group?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, bcc

I received an email as a BCC. Is it possible to find out if my email address was used directly in the BCC line, or if an email group was BCC'd and I got the email because I was part of the email group?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot find that out, but it would not matter anyway. When you are in the BCC, only you and the person that sent the email will see your name in the BCC, no one else.

If you do not wish to receive the mail, ask the sender to remove you.

The above is the case if someone uses outlook or outlook distribution groups, contact lists, etc.

If one would to use an online service mailinglist, then you could find out by looking into the header of the mail message. It would show that the mail was sent from a mailinglist service instead.